# Thymeleaf-template not found with embedded tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, embedded-tomcat-8

At my program [sze](https://github.com/opensource21/sze/tree/v3.3.5_20151003) I tried to switch to embedded tomcat. Unfortunately I run into trouble, because the following thymeleaf-construct can't be solved.
`<th:block th:include="/main::head"/>`
The `main.html` is in the same directory as `login.html` which shows the failure.
I got the following exception

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/main", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (login:5)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.standard.fragment.StandardFragment.extractFragment(StandardFragment.java:202) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardFragmentHandlingAttrProcessor.computeFragment(AbstractStandardFragmentHandlingAttrProcessor.java:72) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractFragmentHandlingAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractFragmentHandlingAttrProcessor.java:63) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61) ~[shiro-web-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108) ~[shiro-web-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137) ~[shiro-web-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) ~[shiro-web-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66) ~[shiro-web-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) ~[shiro-web-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) ~[shiro-web-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) ~[shiro-core-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) ~[shiro-core-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) ~[shiro-core-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) ~[shiro-web-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) ~[shiro-web-1.2.3.jar!/:1.2.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:69) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar!/:8.0.26]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

The strange thing is, that a depoyment of the same war, works fine in tomcat 7 and works fine in eclipse. Only the embedded tomcat in spring-boot 1.2.6 makes trouble. I have no special tomcat or thymeleaf-configuration. It's difficult to debug. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem by setting the loglevel for `org.thymeleaf` to `TRACE`. The problem seems to be the Slash at the beginning. It ends with a lookup of `"classpath:/templates//main.html"`. Which seems not to be resolvable for the classloader which is used in spring-boot. The normal classloader seems to handle this as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's standard JDK behaviour to not find a resource with a double-slash in its path in a jar file. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1744 for some more details.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I just wonder that it works under Tomcat.

Comment: The unwanted behaviour only occurs when loading a resource from jar/war. By default Tomcat unpacks a war when it's deployed so it's not affected as the resource is loaded straight from the file system.

Comment: Your solution helped me out. Strange thing here is that when i run spring boot with embedded tomcat on localhost for dev profile the leading slash is working. When i copy the packaged jar to a server and start that jar the leading slash is a problem - with the same embedded tomcat. on the prod server there is jdk11 on my development pc there is jdk15. is that the reason? anyway - strange but it works